# Which origin fact is true about the Skeksis?

Tags: canon, dark-crystal, dark-crystal-age-of-resistance

Between the *Dark Crystal* movie and the new Netflix series, the Skeksis’s origin became confusing to me.

In the movie, it was stated that Skeksis came from a great conjunction, splitting up from a different being, the urSkeks. which created the mystics as well.

In the series, it was stated that Skeksis are aliens that just showed up and started making a mess of things. These also are a different group of Skeksis that are in the movie (except for a few notable, like Chamberlain).

Which of these is true/canon?

Comment: I would imagine both are true and they are set in their own separate universes, however, I have never seen either.

Comment: is "Skeksis are aliens" stated as omniscient fact, or only what is believed in-universe? I'm surprised if the former because it completely changes the point of the setting.

Comment: Perhaps there's just a confusion with the urSkeks being rogue aliens outlawed from their planet? When the origin race is named the Fallen, it makes sense that you'd assume they're the same set of bad guys.

Comment: I had the same question about 5mn into the first episode @OrangeDog - it clearly states that the Skeksis came from outside Thra. I didn't think to come ask here because I figured it would be sorted out by the end of the series (which I haven't finished yet)

Comment: not sure why this is getting POB close votes. From at least the first episode of this new prequel series, there is an apparent clear contradiction as to the origin of the Skeksis (as given in the original film). This is answerable one way or the other

Comment: @NKCampbell How is "clear contradiction" not the *opposite* of "answerable one way or the other"?

Comment: @Buzz - maybe my comment wasn't clear. I mean to say that either the information given in the film is correct, or the information given in the new series is correct. The fact that there is an apparent contradiction doesn't make the question opinion based. It means that there is either more information pending in future works that will resolve the inconsistency (in which case the answer could be closed under *that* policy) or there is a correct answer that the production staff / other canon materials can resolve.

Comment: @NKCampbell Production staff of which?  In spite of some familial connections, the two works have no creative staff in common.  Frank Oz's idea of what is the "truth" of the matter is probably irreconcilable with that of Jeffrey Addiss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to the origin of the Skeksis, *The Dark Cyrstal* and *Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance* seem to agree.  In episode 7, the Heretic and Urgoh put on a puppet show explaining the origin of the Skeksis and Mystics, and it's essentially the same: that the Skeksis and Mystics were once one as the UrSkeks, and they need to be re-joined.

As for the Skeksis that appear in *Age of Resistance,* it's been [established canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeksis) from *The Dark Crystal: Creation Myths*, that there were originally 18 UrSkeks that came to Thra, but 8 ended up dying before *The Dark Crystal*, with two being killed very soon after [the Great Division](https://darkcrystal.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Division).  (Though as many as 21 different Skeksis names have been listed in the various media.)  So if *Age of Resistance* is closely following the established canon (though already there is evidence of some deviation), we can expect to see at most 16 Skeksis.  Some Skeksis that appeared in *The Dark Crystal* have not appeared in *Age of Resistance*, as of the first season, but are definitely around somewhere, as they are mentioned in dialog in episode 10, along with skekLi the Satirist and skekSa the Mariner who only have appeared in the graphic novels.

Those that appear in both *The Dark Crystal* and *Age of Resistance*:

- skekso the Emperor
- skekSil the Chamberlain
- skekZok the Ritual Master
- skekTek the Scientist
- skekAyuk the Gourmand
- skekEkt the Ornamentalist
- skekOk the Scroll Keeper

The following Skeksis appear in *Age of Resistance* but not *The Dark Crystal*, though most or all were previously named in some of the various other media:

- skekVar the General
- skekLach the Collector
- skekMal the Hunter
- skekGra the Conqueror / the Heretic

Those that appear only in *The Dark Crystal*:

- skekUng the Garthim Master
- skekNa the Slave Master
- skekShod the Treasurer

Comment: From wikipedia the other 4 (to make 18 total) are skekLi the Satirist and skekSa the Mariner (or the Captain) both of whom are mentioned in Age of Resistance, and skekHak (the Carpenter as an urSkek) and skekYi (role unknown). The latter 2 are killed immediately after the split.